# Do I need to define metrics in model.compile in order to use them later?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am trying to train a model and after it is train, I want to see TP TN FP FN, recall, precision, and Sensitivity. Do I need to define all these metrics when I compile the model like this?

```
metrics = [CategoricalAccuracy(),Precision(),Recall(),TruePositives(),TrueNegatives(),FalseNegatives(),FalsePositives(),SensitivityAtSpecificity(0.5)]
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate = 0.004), loss=CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits = True), metrics=metrics)
```

What I want to do is after the model is trained, I want to evaluate it with these metrics and see how it did on the test set. If I run model.evaluate, are the metrics used in model.compile going to be used or can I define more metrics when I am doing evaluation? For example I want to monitor accuracy during training and then Recall/Precision and so on when I evaluate.

Comment: [You could use scikit learn's classification report](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html)

Comment: @Djinn oh yeah I could use that. But My question is, when I run model.evaluate, the metrics that will be used are the ones in model.compile or can I add more metrics? For example I want to monitor accuracy and loss during training and then evaluate with Precision, Recall and so on. Do I need to define those in compile as well?

Comment: If you don't want to monitor Precision, Recall you don't have to put them on compile. You can simply use `tf.keras.metrics.Precision()` after getting predictions using `model.predict`. But if you want to use `model.evaluate` you need to put them on `model.compile`

Comment: @VishalBalaji that's supposed to be the correct answer, thus post it as that, in order to help others in the future to find it more easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to monitor Precision, Recall you don't have to put them on compile. You can simply use `tf.keras.metrics.Precision()` after getting predictions using `model.predict`. But if you want to use `model.evaluate` you need to put them on `model.compile`. This is because `model.evaluate` makes use only of the metrics mentioned when you compile the model, which are initiated when you call `model.compile`